# Get response header jquery ajax post Set-Cookie

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, rest, youtrack

I am using YouTrack for our tracking system. Youtrack comes with a rest webservice that you can call to get information from the system. I am having problem getting authorized and is getting forbidden all the time.

I do my post to their login, and I get the "login ok" respone, and if I check in firebug I can see that the headers are set correctly, but the cookie does not get created. For that I need to get the value from the response header, Set-Cookie.

The post looks like this.

```
      $.post(youTrackLoginUrl, { login: "restUser", password: "qwerty" }, function(data, text, xhr) {

      // do something 

      });
```

And the response and request looks like this.

Response headers:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   Set-Cookie: YTJSESSIONID=91541168A3E0FF9BBB02A8D427D70127; Path=/
>   jetbrains.charisma.main.security.PRINCIPAL=NjVlODRiZTMzNTMyZmI3ODRjNDgxMjk2NzVmOWVmZjNhNjgyYjI3MTY4YzBlYTc0NGIyY2Y1OGVlMDIzMzdjNTpyZXN0VXNlcg; Expires=Wed, 09-Oct-2013 09:47:48 GMT; Path=/
>   Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform, must-revalidate
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: a.domain.com
>   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
>   Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Date: Tue, 09 Oct 2012 09:47:48 GMT

Request:

> POST /rest/user/login HTTP/1.1
>   Host: b.eelab.se
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
>   Accept: */*
>   Accept-Language: sv-se,sv;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>   Referer: http://intra.eelab.se/kontakt/it-vad-jobbar-vi-pa-nu/
>   Content-Length: 30
>   Origin: http://a.domain.com
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Cache-Control: no-cache

I need the Set-Cookie value to create the cookie on the site. What can I do to achive this?

/Cheers.

Comment: did my answer work for you? If so can you mark it correct?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

$.post(youTrackLoginUrl, { login: "restUser", password: "qwerty" }, function(data, text, xhr) {

  data_set_cookie = data.match(/Set-Cookie:\s([^;]+);/)[1];
  createCookie(data_set_cookie.split("=")[0],data_set_cookie.split("=")[1],365); //sets cookie for 1 year

});
```