# AJAX reading ETag after a POST request

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I was wondering, how can I read an ETag that is attached to a server response for a client side POST request that has occured through ajax. At the moment I am POSTing like this from the client side and I get the actual body of the response from the server:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        accepts: "text/plain",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/somewhere",
        data: JSON.stringify(someObject),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8", 
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            window.alert("Received back: '" + data + "'");
        },
        username: theUsername,
        password: thePassword
    });
```

The server responds to the POST request by setting the headers like this:

```
res.writeHead (200, {"ETag": "\"" + anETag + "\"", "Content-Type": "text/plain"});
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8", and         dataType: "text", what ?

Comment: I am sending a JSON and expect a response in plain text (string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Get response header jquery ajax post Set-Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797331/get-response-header-jquery-ajax-post-set-cookie)

Basically the third param in the success function is the XHR request:

```
...
success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('ETag'));
}
...
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. It was very easy as I expected! Have a great day! I will accept as soon as I am allowed.